# PHP variable from file1 to filesA-Z

Tags: php, include

So I've seen some controversy on passing variables from file to file with PHP. What is the "best way" to do it?

Currently, I've got a setup like this

**FILE 1:**

```
<? $foo = 'somethingCoolHere';
$bar = 'nothingLameThere'; ?>
```

**FILE A:**

```
<? include('/link/to/file1.php');
printf('stuff' .$foo. 'stuff'); ?>
```

**FILE B:**

```
<? include('/link/to/file1.php');
printf('stuff' .$foo. 'stuff');
printf('stuff' .$bar. 'stuff'); ?>
```

This works, 'alright'. But if someone wants to expand on what I've got, they may need to remember to include the "include" on the top line to get the variables to work. Is there a "better practice" or "best practice" way vs what I'm doing now?

Comment: No that is it. That is how web config files for MediaWiki and stuff work. If it aint broke dont fix it

Comment: So if someone takes the code i've got and wants to add files to it, they should just be smart enough to add `include('/link/to/file1.php');` to the top?

Comment: Yes. That is how it should work.

Comment: This is pretty much too genericized to get what you want, but there's nothing wrong with what you are doing other than that the short tag `<?` isn't necessarily supported on all PHP installations (it relies on a setting in php.ini)

Comment: I'm actually using the full tag `<?php` just short on here. I'm glad you brought that up though, I was unaware of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally (not sure if others will agree), I would use absolute paths when including files. And I would have those paths sit in constants. Why? Because if I ever needed to change a path (say I moved a file or something) I would not have to go through every file to change the path, but instead, just the file where the constants were defined.

An example:

constant.php

```
define('file1' , 'abolute/path/to/file1');
define('fileA' , 'abolute/path/to/fileA');
define('fileB' , 'abolute/path/to/fileB');
```

Then include constant.php in any file you need to use the constants:

something.php:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/constant.php');//we now have access to our constants
include_once(fileA);
include_once(fileB);
include_once(file1);
```

I'm not saying that method is the best practice, but it would just be something I would do in just about all my projects. And I can't see anything wrong with it either.

Comment: I've been using absolute paths. Though I didn't even think about the "define" function. That would help clean up some of my code a bit. So for expanding to improve what I've got, I'll accept this :)

Answer (score 1):

I follow a similar pattern for my projects either, but there is one thing I would like to point out in your code. Suppose if multiple programmers are working on a large project then it would be difficult to keep track of variables defined in different files. So I always make sure that associative arrays are used to group similar values instead of using individual variables for each. You could consider using the following structure.

**FILE 1:**

```
<?php 
  $file1['foo'] = 'somethingCoolHere';
  $file1['bar'] = 'nothingLameThere';
?>
```

**FILE A:**

```
<?php
  include('file1.php');
  printf('stuff' .$file1['foo']. 'stuff');
?>
```

**FILE B:**

```
<?
  include('file1.php');
  printf('stuff' .$file1['foo']. 'stuff');
  printf('stuff' .$file1['bar']. 'stuff');
?>
```

In this way you can organize the data and moreover makes code reviewing and later development less daunting.